# Firebird "For Each Row" trigger syntax

Tags: firebird, firebird2.5

There is confusion in the documentation and searching online about the support for statement and row level triggers. According to the documentation I've seen the latest version of Firebird supports both statement and row level triggers.

Firebird supposedly supports SQL-92/99. The standard approach for this is to use "for each row" in the trigger SQL, however, this causes an error in firebird.

Here is my statement level trigger, which works:

```
CREATE TRIGGER myExampleTrigger FOR myTable
    AFTER UPDATE
    AS
    BEGIN
       POST_EVENT 'testEvent';
    END;
```

Here is my row level trigger, which doesn't work:

```
CREATE TRIGGER myExampleTrigger FOR myTable
    AFTER UPDATE
    AS 
    FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
       POST_EVENT 'testEvent';
    END;
```

The statement-level trigger works to post an event for updates on myTable.  When I update multiple rows it will only post one event.

What is the syntax for the trigger statement to get it to do a row-level trigger so that I can post an event FOR EACH ROW that is updated?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firebird does not have statement-level triggers. Just create it as the first. It's a row-level trigger.

You said it posts only one event. It seems you also didn't understood how Firebird events works. It will be posted a single time, but you can see how many times by the event counter. They're are posted on commit.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer on using event_counter.  I've looked all over the documentation and I still can't find the syntax for including it in a trigger.  I found some examples on using event_count in stored procedures, but not triggers.  Do you know the syntax?

Comment: The counters are retrieved by the event callback. It's somewhat trick, but you'll sure found some example.

Comment: @mpearso3 Why would you need the event counter in a trigger: just post the event. It should only be of interest to those who registered for the event notification.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I understand that it is only of interest for those who registered for it, but the reason I wanted the event_counter is to allow me to see how many times the event was fired or post the event multiple times based on how many rows were effected.

Answer (score 2):

Triggers in Firebird are always row level, never statement level. The documentation (Interbase 6.0 Language Reference, page 82; available from the [Firebird website](http://www.firebirdsql.org/en/reference-manuals/)) says:

> `CREATE TRIGGER` defines a new trigger to a database. A trigger is a self-contained
>   program associated with a table or view that automatically performs an action **when a
>   row in the table or view is inserted, updated, or deleted**.

As Adriano already explained, events are sent on transaction commit. If you post the same event multiple times in a single transaction, only a single event will be posted (with the count in the event).

Events are used to signal to other applications, not to the database itself (that is what triggers itself are for), so - afaik - you can't register for, nor determine the event count from within a trigger or stored procedure. The application registers for events. How this is done depends on the programming language and driver.

A lot of the (old) Interbase documentation shows example using `EVENT INIT` and `EVENT WAIT`, this however is only for embedded SQL which requires a preprocessor and is really hardly used. With Java and Jaybird you can use [`FBEventManager`](http://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/drivers_documentation/java/2.2.5/docs/) to listen for events, with C# and the Firebird .net provider you can use `FbRemoteEvent`. If you use the Firebird C API you need to use `isc_que_events`.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  In the firebird documentation I found event_count in stored procedure:                               CREATE PROCEDURE send_times(event_count integer)
AS
DECLARE VARIABLE nr INTEGER;
BEGIN
    nr = 1;
    WHILE (nr < event_count) DO
    BEGIN
         POST_EVENT 'MY_EVENT';
         nr = nr + 1;
    END
END [link](http://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/papers_presentations/Power_Firebird_events.pdf)

Comment: @mpearso3 Could you link to that documentation?

Comment: And as far as row-level vs statement-level triggers, my understanding is that row-level will fire if it is a multiple update/insert at once into the table you register for: [row-level vs statement-level](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10167346/row-level-trigger-vs-statement-level-trigger).  If firebird is row-level then why does it only fire that trigger once even when I update multiple rows?

Comment: @mpearso3 The trigger fires for each row. Don't confuse the fact that the event is signaled only once (on transaction commit!) with the number of times the trigger was invoked.