# How to create trigger to take value from another table depends of value from first table

Tags: sql, triggers, firebird

I'm lost with triggers in SQL

Have one main table with all data, second table is only for support of first table. I need a trigger to get value from second table depends of value from first table.

`first_table`

```
 id | name | surname | age | category |
 --------------------------------------
 1  | John | Duck    | 30  |          |
```

`second_table`

```
id | age | category |
---------------------
1  | 30  | adult    |
2  | 12  | kid      |
```

Trigger will autofill column `category` from second table to first table and use age.

I'm trying to add a trigger to the first table:

```
CREATE TRIGGER addCategory
AFTER UPDATE ON first_table FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN 
    DECLARE age int;
    SELECT category INTO table_one FROM table_two WHERE category = category;
    UPDATE table_one set category = NEW.category WHERE age = age;
END
```

Any tips?

result:

`first_table`

```
 id | name | surname | age | category |
 --------------------------------------
 1  | John | Duck    | 30  |  adult   |  <- value from second_table
```

Comment: Based on your code, you are trying to insert into ```table_one``` when it is being updated. But you expect another workflow. What I can see, is that whenever you updated ```second_table``` you want also update the corresponding row from the```first_table```. In that case, you need to create UPDATE trigger for the second table and based on tables relationship update first's table row category. For that purpose you need to use ```INSERT INTO MyTable (SomeValue)
  SELECT SomeOtherValue
  FROM MyOtherTable```

Comment: My bad, i need when insert data to firts_table need from trigger autofill column categories depends on age value

Comment: What are `table_two` and `table_one`? Did you mean `first_table` and `second_table`? If you want to change the values for a table, use a `BEFORE UPDATE` trigger (maybe `BEFORE INSERT OR UDPATE`), and modify through the `NEW` context variable, don't execute an update on the table the trigger fires for. Also, be aware, `FOR EACH ROW` is not valid Firebird [syntax](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/chunk/en/refdocs/fblangref40/fblangref40-ddl-trigger.html#fblangref40-ddl-trgr-create).

Comment: `depends on age value` - what exactly is this dependency? how is it formulated in your database? is it some magic constant, or dictionary table, or what? Create all the sample tables with all the needed data and sample queries in https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=firebird_3.0

Comment: @Arioch'The ````second_table```` is static, ````age```` and ````category```` are defined. My goal is take ````age```` from ````first_table```` and compare with ````second_table```` and return and insert *category* to ````first_table````

Comment: Please, create all the sample tables with all the needed data and sample queries in dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=firebird_3.0, so everyone, us and you, could test their queries and their results

Answer (score 2):

```
CREATE TRIGGER so_70683210
ACTIVE BEFORE UPDATE ON first_table POSITION 0
AS
BEGIN
  SELECT category
    FROM second_table
   WHERE second_table.age = NEW.age
    INTO NEW.category;
END
```

Comment: Whilst many people seem using `FOR EACH ROW` to loop though all table rows, your answer suggests using the `ACTIVE` keyword and `POSITION 0`. It makes sense only updating the row being edited, but appart from your answer I could find no mention of the `ACTIVE` keyword. Same for `POSITION 0`. Are these undocumented? Can you explain their role? Thanks.

Comment: @OuzoPower these are [Firebird extensions to SQL on triggers](https://firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/chunk/en/refdocs/fblangref30/fblangref30-ddl-trigger.html#fblangref30-ddl-trgr-create).  Firebird does not support explicit `FOR EACH ROW` specification — [all its DML triggers are "row level"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24832023/132382) triggers.

Answer (score -3):

when i change *firebird* to *sqlite* this works:

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER tr
 AFTER INSERT ON first_table
 BEGIN
 UPDATE first_table SET category = (SELECT CATEGORY FROM second_table 
 WHERE second_table.AGE = first_table.AGE) WHERE CATEGORY = NEW.CATEGORY;
 END;
```

Comment: Update of just inserted record with value from subselect... Not everything that "works" should be used in real life.

Comment: @user13964273 and why ? what is worng in my code ?

Comment: As said: update of just inserted record is bad from engine POV: a lot of unnecessary work, waste of disk space and I/O. Using of subselect may be not that bad depending on plan but it is error-prone. A little mistype and whole table is updated but nobody notice that because new values are the same as old one, just awful performance and mysterious update conflicts and even that may left unnoticed in single-user system.

Comment: This is not an answer to your own question.