# Oracle validate range for overlapping value

Tags: database, oracle, validation, oracle11g, triggers

I am trying to validate range value in Oracle table. The table name YEAR_RANG is like this

```
ID  YEAR_FROM  YEAR_TO
1       1950    1980
2       2001    2009
3       2010    2015
4       2016    2020
```

Here I want to make a constraint that the year range of two row can't overlap. I am trying to do it using the following trigger,

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER YEAR_RANG_VALID
BEFORE INSERT or UPDATE on YEAR_RANG
FOR EACH ROW
  DECLARE
    o_exst NUMBER;
  BEGIN
    select count(*) into o_exst
    FROM YEAR_RANG
    WHERE
      id != :new.id
      and GREATEST(YEAR_FROM,:new.YEAR_FROM) <= LEAST(YEAR_TO,:new.YEAR_TO)
      and ROWNUM = 1;
    IF o_exst = 1 THEN
      raise_application_error( -20202, 'Range overlap');
    END IF;
  END;
```

This works for input but for update, it is giving this error

```
[42000][4091] ORA-04091: table DB.YEAR_RANG is mutating, trigger/function may not see it
ORA-06512: at "DB.YEAR_RANG_VALID", line 4
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'DB.YEAR_RANG_VALID'
```

Changing to "after INSERT or UPDATE on YEAR_RANG" also don't helping. How can I do the validation check? Is my trigger is ok or there is better way?

And one more thing, I can't check this in application level as this was called from a generic CRUD framework, DB fail is only way there to detect constraint fail.

Comment: You can't create a trigger that fetch values in the same table you are inserting, at least not of type BEFORE. See if you can get it with AFTER insert or update. Don't recall if it is possible though.

Comment: Also see http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/testcontent/o58asktom-101055.html

Comment: @JorgeCampos After inser or update also don't work.

Comment: @TigerCoder Have you tried a statement level trigger? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10167346/row-level-trigger-vs-statement-level-trigger

Comment: Since this table will clearly only ever have a small number of rows, @vercelli's suggestion of a statement-level trigger is very appropriate: just check that after the statement **no** overlapping rows exist in the table. (If the table had millions of rows then you wouldn't want to do that.)

Comment: @vercelli a statement level trigger was the answer. Thanks for the info. If you could give your comment as answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `FOR EACH ROW` to make it  a statement level trigger. [row-level trigger vs statement-level trigger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10167346/row-level-trigger-vs-statement-level-trigger)