# Why do we want to use FOR EACH ROW in SQL?

Tags: oracle

I've been studying SQL for a while, and I understand the difference between a row level trigger and a statement level trigger. What I do not understand is, why do we want to use a row level trigger using FOR EACH ROW clause, while we can use a statement level trigger? To my knowledge, statement level trigger fires once for each statement. Isn't that more efficient than firing on a row basis? If there are any other reasons to use it, could you specify them as well?

Lastly, could you explain this based on the Oracle DBMS? Appreciate it(:

In terms of "difference" I am more interested in why and how one trigger works better than the other (if it does happens),  instead of definition wise. I hope this clarifies my question.

[Update] The answer provided by pinaki [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10167346/row-level-trigger-vs-statement-level-trigger) has explained a thing or two. But I wonder if there are any other uses that distinguishes the 2 triggers? Thanks for any patient enlightenment(:

Comment: Can you provide an example? Stack Overflow strongly encourages questions with a concrete basis for asking.

Comment: row locking vs tabling locking?

Comment: @tadman Unfortunately I don't have any at hand, and I am not sure how to come up with an appropriate one. Would you care to share one?

Comment: @Bindrid Could you elaborate it?

Comment: Depending on settings, code etc, you can lock an entire table until the transaction is complete or just row.  That way if a another user is trying to get different data from the same table, they are not blocked until the transaction is complete.

Comment: @Bindrid That helped. Cheers(: